# How can I use JNLP to download Java 7?

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start, java-7

I'm developing a rich Internet application that requires a Java 7 platform.  How can its associated JNLP file ensure the installation of that platform?

I've tried several variations on the following in the JNLP file (mostly playing with the URL in the "href" attribute):

```
<jnlp ...>
  ...
  <resources>
    <java version="1.7+" href="http://download.java.net/jdk7/m5"/>
    ...
  </resources>
</jnlp>
```

but nothing seems to work -- I always wind up being sent [here](http://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp?host=java.com&returnPage=dynaccn.jnlp&locale=en-US), where there is no Java 7 release.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as a quick google search says, Java 7 has not offically been "released" yet -- you can get [the latest early access snapshots](https://jdk7.dev.java.net/), but it seems September 2010 or later is the release date.

Comment: I know it hasn't been released.  The question is whether or not it can still be downloaded via JNLP.

Comment: In the section about JRE resources, the JNLP File Syntax documention repeatedly uses the URL "http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se". It also does not state that "java" is a valid resource (like how you are using it), so take that with a grain of salt. I would assume that until Java 7 is completely released it would not be supported in Web Start.

Just out of curiosity, though, why are you requiring Java 7? There are some great improvements but I'm not sure if I personally would put into the field something that uses technology that bleeding-edge.

Comment: I need the directory monitoring capabilities of Java 7.  Also, I happen to agree with the design tip that Alan Cooper gave in chapter 10 of "About Face": "The program should perform optimally on hardware that doesn't exit yet." (after substituting "platform" for hardware", of course).

Answer (score 0):

Java Web Start is not open sourced with the JDK (alas), so this is still implementation dependent and we cannot refer to the official Oracle Java source to indicate how this should be done.

There are developer builds of Java 7 out in the wild now.  You can start experimenting with it to at least get this right for when it is officially released.